# Table is no longer updating to firebase, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I recently change the way I am passing data into my table.I am using a Class to pass data to the component.

```js
export function EmployeeClass(data) {
  if (typeof data.first_name !== "undefined" && data.first_name) {
    this.first_name = data.first_name;
  } else {
    this.first_name = "";
  }
  if (typeof data.last_name !== "undefined" && data.last_name) {
    this.last_name = data.last_name;
  } else {
    this.last_name = "";
  }

this.getData = () => {
    var data = {};
    data.first_name = this.first_name;
    data.last_name = this.last_name;
return data
```

I then call a function in the main component to get all the employees from the firestore DB

```js
function getEmployees() {
    let ref = firestoreDb
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .collection("employees");
    // .where("store_id", "==", currentStore.id);
    firestoreRead(ref).then(
      snapshot => {
        let newEmployees = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
          let employeeData = doc.data();
          employeeData["id"] = doc.id;
          employeeData["default_department"] = false;
          let newEmployee = new EmployeeClass(employeeData);
          newEmployees.push(newEmployee);
        });
        newEmployees.sort((a, b) => {
          return a.last_name < b.last_name;
        });
        setEmployees(newEmployees);
      },
      [userId]
    );
  }
```

This data then gets passed to a table component that renders onto the screen. This part still works fine, as all the employees and their data is visible on the table, what isn't working is the update component.

upon save I call this `updateEmployee` function that calls my firestore update. When I console.log 
`newData` as you can see below, it spits out the data already populating the table, not the updated data that I am looking for.

```js
function updateEmployee() {
    let newData = props.employee.getData();

    let deptRef = firestoreDb
      .collection("users")
      .doc(userId)
      .collection("employees")
      .doc(props.employee.id);
    firestoreUpdate(deptRef, newData)
      .then(doc => console.log(newData))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your intention correctly, you want `updateEmployee()` to refresh the data you have in your table with the data stored in the database.

A [Firestore update operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) is a special type of **write operation** that allows you to modify specific properties of a document instead of overwriting the entire document using a set operation. In your current `updateEmployee()` function, you take the data you have on your client device and upload it to the server, rather than read the data from the server back to your device.

Because of this special meaning of `update` in the context of Firestore, I'd suggest renaming the function to `refreshEmployee()` instead.

```js
function refreshEmployee() {
    let employeeRef = firestoreDb
      .collection("users")
      .doc(userId)
      .collection("employees")
      .doc(props.employee.id);

    employeeRef.get()
      .then((doc) => {
          if (!doc.exists) { throw 'not found'; }

          let latestData = doc.data();
          props.employee.first_name = latestData.first_name || "";
          props.employee.last_name = latestData.last_name || "";
          console.log('Refreshed data: ' + JSON.stringify(props.employee.getData()));

          // TODO: update values displayed in table
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

---

#### Other notes

I would consider moving the refresh operation inside of `EmployeeClass` so that updating itself with new data from the server is as simple as `props.employee.refresh()`. This would mean passing in a database reference in the `EmployeeClass` constructor.

In Javascript, the logic provided by the following code:

```js
if (typeof data.last_name !== "undefined" && data.last_name) {
  this.last_name = data.last_name;
} else {
  this.last_name = "";
}
```

can be compressed down to just `this.last_name = data.last_name || "";` with the same effect of if `data.last_name` is `undefined` or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), fall back to the value of `""`.